# How can I measure distance in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

How can I measure the distance between two points in Google Maps? I just can't find any solution for it!

Comment: I'd suggest using *Google Earth* instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can enable the Distance Measurement Tool from the [Labs section of Google Maps](http://maps.google.com/?showlabs=1).

> #### Distance Measurement Tool
>
> Measure the distance of a path on the Earth

Comment: This link doesn't appear to work any longer

Answer (score 3):

If you mean straight-line distance, then start to create a custom map and draw a line on it.   Note the length that the line is (it's shown in the line dialog box) - then abandon your custom map without saving.

Comment: This is great, as it is a built-in tool in Maps. You can measure the distance of any custom path you create, not only just a straight line.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Planimeter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vistechprojects.planimeter) app on Google Play. It makes all kinds of measurements on Google Maps, it's paid though.

Comment: This is webapps. Planimeter doesn't help those who aren't using android.

Answer (score 1):

Log into google maps with your gmail account. Under the button for "create map" click "or create with Classic My Maps" and name your new map in the title field. The fully featured hand drag, location pin drop, and measurement line tool icons will reappear on the map where they used to be in earlier versions of google maps, in the upper left of the map, enabling you to select the measurement line tool and click along the route you want to measure, and save the route along with the pin drop custom place locations. Click the line tool again to complete your route outline, which gives measurements by start to finish dynamically as you draw.

When you want to find your map again, remember to click "google classic maps" again under your maps list, since google's new default maps view doesn't show the classic custom maps by default.

Comment: This! This is up to date!

Answer (score 0):

You can use my Chrome extension named [Maps Ruler for Google Maps](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/maps-ruler-for-google-map/eljpanecjjlonmoiofelcmkkpojcalcb) to measure distance in Google Maps.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: A chrome extension Isn't a "webapp" especially when there is a [webapp solution](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/53607/687)