# Measure distances on New Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to use Google Maps in order to measure the distance along a path. I would like to mark out my path by clicking points on the map. I remember having done this some months ago with some difficulty but I don't find a way to do this using the new Google Maps.

Is there a way to do this? Are there alternatives?

Comment: you can't do so in new Maps. You'll have to switch to classic Maps. After that, measurement is available in Labs [How can I measure distance in Google Maps?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/22106)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the desired result correctly, you should be able to just click the directions button on the new Google maps search at the top left, enter your start end end points, and then click on the path and drag at various points to alter where it goes.  The summary on the left below the start & end points tells you the distance, as well as the balloon that pops up along the path.

In this picture, the default route it sends you on goes out of Red River west, but I drug a point over to Eagle Nest to alter it and see how far it was.

[image]

Comment: The reason I did not want to go with this solution was because in some cases, dragging a point aside creates a diversion which breaks off from the main path and returns immediately. 

But I got it to work by dragging other neighboring points. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, luckily you can drag basically an infinite number of points along the path, if needed, to get it spot on.  Glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 0):

Try [Google Earth](http://www.google.com/earth/). There you can draw segments and measure distances.